# Can a chrome extension or javascript monitor other chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, websecurity

I want to protect a webpage's data from the extensions which have permission to read the site's data. I guess some kind of protection must be done on the client side for this purpose. As per my knowledge, there can be two methods using the default Chrome browser; first use javascript or second use a custom extension. But I am doubtful whether any of them can identify the presence of the extensions which have this permission.

Any other method for accomplishing the tasks is also welcome.